# Getting "The caller does not have permission" when trying to updateBillingInfo

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to programmatically update billing account for one of my projects. I'm using node client library for googleapis REST. This is my code:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const cloudbilling = google.cloudbilling('v1');
async function main() {
  let authClient;
  try {
    authClient = await authorize();
    console.log('AUTH', authClient);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  const request = {            
      name: "projects/rensi-28",   
      requestBody: {
        billingAccountName: "billingAccounts/My Billing Account" 
      }    
           
  };
  google.options({auth: authClient});
  try {
    const response = (await cloudbilling.projects.updateBillingInfo(request)).data;    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error:', err);
  }
  
}
main();

async function authorize() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  return await auth.getClient();
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
errors: [
    {
      message: 'The caller does not have permission',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden'
    }
  ]
```

I'm using a service account and environment variable is correctly set, because I can create projects and use other APIs.

My service account has these roles:

| Level | Role |
| --- | --- |
| Project | Project Billing Manager |
| Project | Owner |
| Organization | Billing Account Administrator |
| Organization | Billing Account Creator |
| Organization | Project Billing Manager |
| Organization | Billing Account Viewer |
| Organization | Owner |
| Billing Account | Billing Account Administrator |
| Billing Account | Billing Account User |
| Billing Account | Billing Account Viewer |

If enable billing from gcloud with same service account it works:

```
gcloud alpha billing projects link p001  --billing-account 45FG32-45FG32-45FG32
```

```
gcloud alpha billing projects link p001  --billing-account 45FG32-45FG32-45FG32
```

```
billingAccountName: billingAccounts/45FG32-45FG32-45FG32
billingEnabled: true
name: projects/p001/billingInfo
projectId: bxtrb-rensi-28
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the names of the parameters are not clear,  try to use

project id instead of the project name
and instead of billing  account  name use billing account id

```
const request = { 
      name: "projects/rensi-28",   // projectId
      requestBody: {
        billingAccountName: "billingAccounts/My Billing Account" //billingAcountId
      }    
           
  };
```

Comment: Yes, I was using project name and billing account name, and project id and billing account id was needed

Answer (score 2):

The format of the `billingAccountName` is incorrect.

Use the format `billingAccounts/45FG32-45FG32-45FG32`.

Reference: [ProjectBillingInfo](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/ProjectBillingInfo).

Comment: Thank you  the billing account name and the project id  was incorrect